# Why is a yeoman scaffold so slow?

Tags: npm, yeoman

A simple `yo webapp` with a freshly installed Yeoman 1.4.6 and a freshly installed Node.js 0.12 (I've also tested with 0.10) takes four minutes on my computer!  I'm wondering if things are configured as they should. Does npm have to download do all these things every time? What happened since [Paul Irish initial demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mk-tFn2Ix6g)?

My system is an Ubuntu 14.10, Node.js 0.12 installed using [these instructions](https://nodesource.com/blog/nodejs-v012-iojs-and-the-nodesource-linux-repositories).

**Update:** Here's an asciicast from another machine (Ubuntu 14.04, Node.js 0.10, NPM 2.7.1): https://asciinema.org/a/17741

Answer (score 3):

The "module" concept of node.js is around "download on first install and save to cache for future installs". Basically, then you start `yo webapp` on **fresh** node.js install, **all** required node.js modules are download from internet and saved to cache. Second `yo webapp` command will do much faster (like in demo) since all required modules are already downloaded to your computer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - that makes sense, and how I figured things should be, but was not the case for me. The "yo webapp" I clocked to four minutes was not the first one. So I assume something's broken with my cache setup? (Updated question with system info)

Comment: I now tried on another system, same results. This time a Ubuntu 14.04 system. On this machine, I did `apt-get install nodejs nodejs-legacy npm` and then set up npm to install global modules in my home directory following [these instructions](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions) (Option 2). Then update npm: `npm install -g npm`. Then `npm install -g yo bower grunt-cli generator-webapp`. Then for every `yo webapp`, the `npm install` step takes forever, downloads lots of modules to node_modules. Can't I install these globally?